# How to make select from two table in php

Tags: php

I want to inquire about the result of the student with his name ..
Where the result in a table and the name of the student in another table
How can it

This student's table: `std_id, std_name`

This result table : `re_id, result, std_id`

this is my code

```html
<table dir="rtl"style="margin-right: 10px;" id="rounded-corner" summary="2007 Major IT Companies' Profit" style="margin-left:150px;">
    <thead>
     <tr>
             <th width="211" class="rounded" scope="col"></th>
             <th width="211" class="rounded" scope="col">الاسم</th>
             <th width="211" class="rounded" scope="col">النتيجة</th>       
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
       $s=mysql_query("select std_id,std_na from students ");
       while($row=mysql_fetch_object($s))
       {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->std_id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->std_na; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->result; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you post the DB structure ? you will need to do a `JOIN`

Comment: so have two table student  and result , column in student table is std_id, std_name and column in result table is re_id,result,std_id.   you want output to show students name with their  result in table. right ?

Comment: please stop using `mysql_query`, it has been depreciated since php 5.5, and completely removed from php 7.0.0. Instead use PDO which is the current go to method for safe database queries.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to learn first of all joining

use like this

```
SELECT students_table.std_name, results_table.result FROM students_table LEFT JOIN results_table ON students_table.std_id = results_table.std_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This it will work .

```
SELECT `student`.`std_name`, `result`.`result` FROM `student`,`result` where `student`.`std_id`=`result`.`std_id
```

your table name student and result , if your table name is different then just change table name, the query willl be same.